# Discharge during urination after ejaculation

Tags: taharah, ghusl

Asalamalaykum everyone

I am having an issue, basically what happened is that I masturbasted, and I thought all the semen had been released, so I urinated to make sure that there was no semen in the passage. a few hours later when I used the washroom, I saw some other liquid substance that was about to come out while I was peeing, but I held it in, this has happened before, when after ejaculation, I urinated and made ghusl, but after going to the washroom some hours later some sticky discharge came out after I was done peeing, there was no desire or anything, I am very confused should I do ghusl again? Or is this permissible, please help.

Comment: But my doubt is, Is Masturbation is permissible?

Comment: @AkbarBadhusha I would recommend you to watch zakir naik's video on this topic. He has two videos regarding this. [One](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDFxGu47Zu0), [Two](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IC3b_ABrNxY).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to re-do your ghusl for sexual discharge unless you have both ejcaulation and semen discharge at the same time. See hadith below:

Narrated `Ali:

I used to get emotional urethral discharge frequently. Being the son-in-law of the Prophet (ﷺ) I requested a man to ask him about it. So the man asked the Prophet (ﷺ) about it. The Prophet (ﷺ) replied, "Perform ablution after washing your organ (penis)."

حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو الْوَلِيدِ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا زَائِدَةُ، عَنْ أَبِي حَصِينٍ، عَنْ أَبِي عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ، عَنْ عَلِيٍّ، قَالَ كُنْتُ رَجُلاً مَذَّاءً فَأَمَرْتُ رَجُلاً أَنْ يَسْأَلَ النَّبِيَّ صلى الله عليه وسلم لِمَكَانِ ابْنَتِهِ فَسَأَلَ فَقَالَ ‏ "‏ تَوَضَّأْ وَاغْسِلْ ذَكَرَكَ ‏"‏‏.‏
Reference    : Sahih al-Bukhari 269
In-book reference    : Book 5, Hadith 22
USC-MSA web (English) reference  : Vol. 1, Book 5, Hadith 269
(deprecated numbering scheme)

SO you only have to make istinga and wudu.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what do you mean by ""You don't have to re-do your ghusl for sexual discharge unless you have both ejcaulation and semen discharge at the same time""

Comment: @muslim sorry for the late reply, I was stuck in the her majesties royal inn. Simply look up the defination of ejcaulation on the net. I'm sure you will get the picture.